# How to hide rows in tableview. After hideing the index should not change iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, tableview, uitableview

I am having array like this:

```
array = (@"",@"Cricket",@"Planet",@"Football",@"",@"",@"HelloWorld").
```

I am showing in a table view. It showing all objects with null objects also. I want to invisible or hide null rows.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath                                       
 {       
 UITableViewCell* cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];        
 if([array objectisIdenticalto:@""])
{
   return 0;
}else
{
   return 30;
}
```

I need index as same where the value is. I need same indexpath and not show the null values in a tableview. My english is poor pls cooperate and help in the solution.

Comment: just to clarify , you need index like  Cricket - 0,  Planet - 1 etc ??

Comment: I want index path for cricket is 1, planet is 2,football is 3, Helloworld is 6.

Comment: Mithun i think u got it

Comment: ok .. will creating a filtered array which does not contain invalid values and then using it as data source for the tableview work for you ??

Comment: Actually i need to do in this way, when i delete objects using commit editing style method,. I need to delete in database also main array consisting all objects(No null values). i filtered some objects so the result array is like as shown above. So the indexpath must needed

Comment: if i change any objects in this array so the main array also takes that. Here the helloworld is in 6 and in main array also it is in 6. if i change it deletes another object in main array. If u cant understand just ask again

Comment: ok then in the height for row at index path method, just check if [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] is invalid  and then set the height

Answer (score 1):

You're checking if your array is equal to @"" but you want to be checking the object in your array at that index.

Try:

```
...
if ([array[indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@""]) {
    return 0;
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks dan let me try.

Answer (score 0):

What I took from you question is that you want to be able to have some rows nulled and hidden in the tableview. I may be able to help with this.

You will need to pass the heightForRowAtIndexPath a cell height of 0 for any row that is null. Your code may end up looking something like this...

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    float defaultHeightForRow = 30;

    YourCustomCell *cell = (YourCustomCell *) [tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexpath];

    if(cell.tag==3)
        return 0;
    else
        return defaultHeightForRow;
```

This should set any null rows to a height of 0 (which will in effect hide the row), and set the rest of the row heights to the 30 that you designated as the default height.

Hope this will be some help to you. Cheers.